# compute distance, clustering and heatmap of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, heatmap

this is my dataframe describing the pairwise similarity (column ps) between two chromosomes:

```
> head(df)
  miRNA.chr Target.chr      ps
  <ord>     <fctr>   <int>
1      chr1       chr1 4161600
2      chr1       chr2 2547960
3      chr1       chr3 2186880
4      chr1       chr4 1523880
5      chr1       chr5 1799280
6      chr1       chr6 2111400
```

Now this is what I have done:

```
m<-as.matrix(dist(df))
d<-as.dist(m)
h<-hclust(d)
heatmap.2(h$merge,dendrogram = "row")
```

Obviously it doesn't work.

I need an heatmap like this:
[Heatmap in figure 1A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlRXJ.jpg)

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: I wonder if from a table like `df` using the function `as.dist()` you obtain a distance matrix. Does `d` contain the distance matrix you want?

Comment: I assume that you get an error with your first line `m<-as.matrix(dist(df))` Your data frame contains factors.  How will you compute the distance between them?

Comment: I think that all the commands that I have used are wrong except for the command to create m because I obtain a matrix with all 0 on the diagonal and some measure in the other positions.

Comment: I have no errors on the screen, simply I create an heatmap with no sense (only 2 columns and 547 rows when I need 23 columns and 23 rows, one for every chromosome).

Comment: Please explain the structure and values of the data. I take it that each row represents one pairing, and the similarities are the amount of shared material? You will need to convert these to distances (for example by dividing by the maximally possible similarity, then subtracting the result from one). Does the data contain similarity values for both pairs (i.e. similarity(chr1, chr2) as well as similarity(chr2, chr1)) or only in one direction?